# If $\int_{-\infty}^k f(x)dx = .95$ and $f(x)$ is positive even, then $\int_{-k}^k f(x)dx = .10$?

Tags: integration

> If $\int_{-\infty}^k f(x)dx = .95$ and $f(x)$ is positive even, then $\int_{-k}^k f(x)dx = .10$?

Does this seem correct? Or is there not enough information to make the last conclusion?
Say for all real $x$, $f(x) > 0$, $f(x) = f(-x)$, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 1$. If $\int_{-\infty}^k f(x)dx = .95$, then $\int_{-k}^k f(x)dx = .10?$.
Can I assume $k=.05$?

Comment: This does not hold in general, at least for general functions $f(x)$.  You seem to have a few errors:  $k$ is the bound of your integral, and not what the integral evaluates to, so writing $k = 0.05$ is incorrect.  Furthermore, you must have some underlying assumptions about $f(x)$.  Is $f(x)$ an odd function (i.e. symmetric about the $y$-axis)?  If not, then there is no way to know what $\int_{-k}^k f(x) dx$ evaluates to.  If $f(x)$ is symmetric, then you can use that $\int_k^{\infty} f(x) dx = 0.05,$ use symmetry to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{-k} f(x) dx$, and find $\int_{-k}^k$ from there.

Comment: And of course, above, I mean to say if $f(x) is even, not odd!

Answer (score 1):

> and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 1$

It is not clear from the question whether this is a given condition or not. Assuming it is, note that:

$$
\begin{align}
1 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^k f(x)dx + \int_{-k}^\infty f(x)dx - \int_{-k}^k f(x)dx \\
 &= 2 \cdot \int_{-\infty}^k f(x)dx  - \int_{-k}^k f(x)dx \\
 &= 2 \cdot 0.95  - \int_{-k}^k f(x)dx
\end{align}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]   For a visualization of the above:

$$
\underbrace{\rlap{\overbrace{\phantom{\frac{0}{0}-\infty\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad -k\quad\quad\quad 0\quad\quad\quad k}}^{\large=0.95}} \overline{-\infty\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \underbrace{-k\quad\quad\quad 0\quad\quad\quad k\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad +\infty\;}_{\large=0.95 \; \text{because} \;f\; \text{is even}}}}_{\large=1} \\
$$

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question as $f$ is an even function which is a **densify function**, then we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x) \, dx = 0.5$$

and since $$\int_{-\infty}^k f(x) \, dx= 0.95$$

and $f$ is positive everywhere, we have $k>0$.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-k} f(x) \, dx+\int_{-k}^k f(x) \, dx + \int_{k}^\infty f(x) \, dx= 1$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-k} f(x) \, dx+\int_{-k}^k f(x) \, dx = 0.95$$

subtracting the difference,

$$\int_{k}^\infty f(x) \, dx = 0.05$$

Let $y = -x$, then $$-\int_{-k}^{-\infty} f(-y) \, dy=0.05$$

using the information that the function is even,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-k}f(x) \, dx =0.05$$

Hence $$\int_{-k}^k f(x) \, dx =0.9$$

$k$ need not be $0.05$, for example, consider the standard normal distribution.

Remark: If it is not a density function and we know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = M>0$, we can repeat the procedure to deduce the desired quantity.

Answer (score 0):

so if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$

then $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx=1$

and it has been said that $f(x)=f(-x)$ so let $x=-u\,,\frac{dx}{du}=-1$

so $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx=-\int_{\infty}^{0}f(-u)du=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(-x)dx$

again since $f(x)=f(-x)$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(-x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx$

so $2\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$ therefore $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx=0.5$ which is what you said.

now if $\int_{-\infty}^{k}f(x)dx=0.95$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{k}f(x)dx=0.95$ so $\int_{0}^{k}f(x)dx=0.45$

and because $f(x)=f(-x)\,,\int_{-k}^{k}f(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{k}f(x)dx=0.9$

It seems to hold for all even functions provided they can be integated in the domain ${(-\infty,\infty)}$